# How to gather logs from Apple Unified Logging?

Tags: xcode, logging

I'm using the Apple Unified Logging and want to add an option for the user to send me the collected logging data from my macOS app.
Unfortunately I cannot find a way to gather this information.
The only way I found was sysdiagnose but this has to be run from the command line, with root privileges and contains *all* system logs.
As this is quite unhandy for the normal user - is there a way to collect only the logs from my app?
Thanks!